# Filter an Email Report for Criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'd like to receive a daily report of items that are not marked "Completed" in my spreadsheet.  I have the code that will email the report, but I need to add a line or two of code that filters out anything that has a status that is not equal to Completed.  Additionally, as this project grows, I would like to add functionality to filter based on multiple items (e.g. show only items not marked completed in Col D assigned for action to Greg in Col B).

The sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jA4XQa7MgQI7OOLwCcmGv7BcUKSjdIPyh6B0CeQI-PI/edit#gid=0

My code as it stands now...

```
function emailStatusReport() {

  // Set variables. 
  var x = 13;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("report.html");
  var message;
  var subject;
  var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();    
  var theRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var completeMessage = "";
     //Logger.log(theRang.getA1Notation());
  var theManualRange = ss.getRange("A1:C7");
    // var dateTimeStamp = now();
  var vals = theManualRange.getValues();
       for(i=0; i<vals.length; i++){
         var itemNumber = vals[i][0];
         var title = vals[i][1];
         var description = vals[i][2];
         // Logger.log(itemNumber  + " " + title + " " + description + " ");
         completeMessage = completeMessage + ("<BR>" + itemNumber  + " " + title + " " + description + "</BR>");
            }

           Logger.log(completeMessage);

//  Logger.log (x);
//  Logger.log (ss);
//  Logger.log (sheetName);
//  Logger.log ("Remaining email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
//  Logger.log (vals[i][0]);



subject = "Daily Status Report TEST..."
message = "<HTML><BODY>" +          
         "<Font Face='verdana' color='green' size='2'>" + 
         "<P><P><B>Daily Status Report TEST</B>" +
         "<P>Please review the report listed below.  " + 
            // "<P>The value of x is " + x + "." + 

         "<P>" + completeMessage + 
         "<P><P>" + 
         "For the most up-to-date information, please visit: <BR>" + 
         "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jA4XQa7MgQI7OOLwCcmGv7BcUKSjdIPyh6B0CeQI-PI/edit#gid=0" +
         "<P>" + 

         "<P><B>Make it an amazing day!</B>" +

            // "<P>Report generated at: " + dateTimeStamp + ". " +
         "<P>Remaining daily email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining + ". " +          
             // "<P>This report runs between ___ AM and ___ AM." +

           "</HTML></BODY>"; 


MailApp.sendEmail("greg@gregbartonmba.com", subject, "", {htmlBody: message});


//  Logger.log("Subject is :" + subject); 
//  Logger.log("Message is: " + message);




}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question: To receive a daily report of items that are not marked "Completed"

First change  the ManualRange to include status column:

```
var theManualRange = ss.getRange("A1:D7");
```

then change your for loop to:

```
for(i=0; i<vals.length; i++){
         var itemNumber = vals[i][0];
         var title = vals[i][1];
         var description = vals[i][2];
         var status = vals[i][3];

         // Logger.log(itemNumber  + " " + title + " " + description + " ");
         if (status != 'Completed') {
         completeMessage = completeMessage + ("<BR>" + itemNumber  + " " + title + " " + description + "</BR>");
         }
            }
```